# Returning the function itself as a return value

Tags: c, recursion

I have a simple question about returning the value of the function itself. the function of course, is recursive. 
for example:

```
int CountDigs(int n)
{
  int dig=n%10;
  if(n < 10) return 0;
  if( (n/10)%10 > dig )
    return CountDigs(n/10)+1;
  return CountDigs(n/10);
}
```

I usually return a number or a variable so this is the first time I have seen this. Someone can please explain where the value of "+1" stores at the memory, and why shouldn't I create a variable that stores the summary?

To be more specific, I mad the same solution but diffrent:

```
int counting_function(int n)
{
    int sum;
    if (n>=9)
    return 0;
    sum = counting_function (n/10);
    if (n%10 < n/10%10)
    {
        sum++;
        return sum;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Your function does not return itself.  It returns *the result of calling itself*, or a value related to that.  This is a completely different thing.

Comment: You're not returning the function, your returning the value returned by the function.  The _result_ would be the same as `int result = CountDigs(n/10)+1; return result;`

Comment: Your function does not converge: `counting_function(0);` would never finish: 0 is smaller than 9, so the function call recursively with 0/10=0, etc etc. Actually, any number bellow 9 would never finish and any number over 8 would finish immediately.

Comment: Is this a duplicated?

Comment: @AdrianMaire lol I didn't notice, this was a keyboard mistake.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Where return values go depend on the calling convention. In x86, they are usually placed in register EAX (and EDX if more space is needed). The compiler doesn't need an explicit variable named - those are eventually broken down into memory addresses and registers, and in this case (depending again on your calling convention), the math gets done in some registers, with the result being placed in EAX to be used as you pop up the callstack.

Comment: This is not at all an answer to the question. It ha snothing to do with calling conventions. BTW the C language doesn'w know about a calling convention.

Comment: He referenced where in memory the return value would go, so I was trying to get at what he was asking.

Comment: The other answers are better than this one. You're just explaining the very particular case of what most compilers do for the x86 code. But not my downvote BTW.

Answer (score 2):

When a `return` statement returns a value, that value is specified by an expression.  That expression can be a simple one, such as a constant or a variable name, but it does not need to be.  It can be *any* valid expression of suitable type.

> Someone can please explain where the value of "+1" stores at the memory,

That's up to the compiler, but the result of adding 1 probably *isn't* stored in system memory.  More likely than not, it never leaves the CPU.

> and why shouldn't I create a variable that stores the summary?

There's nothing inherently wrong with storing the result in a variable, and then using the variable's name as the `return` expression.  In some cases that might be clearer.  Even then, however, the value might not actually be stored to system memory.  If it *were* stored to system memory, however, then that would be a lot more time consuming than not.

The key thing to understand here is that a `return` statement designates a *value* to return directly, not indirectly.  In most cases, for most compilers, such a return value is communicated to the caller via a CPU register, not system memory, including in particular the cases with which you express familiarity.

Comment: I had been punished by 4 points in my HW for using an "unnecessary" variable while using a recursive call. the reason was "each time you call for the function, you allocate another memory piece for the variable, which can be speared".

Comment: @OfekPintok: if you want to get those 4 points back, examine the assembler output and check if such a temporary variable is actually emitted in the source code. If it's not, step to your teacher and tell that it was optimized away.

Comment: @OfekPintok, when I said "there's nothing *inherently* wrong" I meant that the function produces the same result either way, and the addition of a variable is not costly.  I find the version in which you introduce the variable to be less clear than the one without, but I that doesn't make it wrong.  I cannot speak to the details of the grading rubric applied to your exercise, but I will note that the comment about allocating excess memory reflects a *possibility*, but not a *probability*.  In that particular case, your `sum` variable is likely to reside only in a register.

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statement takes an **expression** and uses that as the return value  of a function.

An expression can be a single variable, the return value of calling a function, a literal value, or any combination of the above with any number of operators putting them together.

There's no need to store an expression in a variable and pass just that variable to `return`.  Any expression of the proper type may be places there.